# Seeking iOS GIS applications/frameworks for mobile data acquisition?

Tags: software-recommendations, ios, data-collection, mobile-gis

I'm starting to develop an application for iPad which should enable the users to go to the field and acquire georeferenced information. The idea is to enable acquisition of points and polygons, and the filling of a set of attributes for the geometry. Also important is the ability to connect to externals geo-referenced databases, such as a PostGIS one.

Ideally, I would want to be somewhat similar to the ArcGIS for iOS application, which has a good user interface.

Can you point me to other applications similar to what I am developing?
I already know the following ones:

- Geo-jot
- pcMapper
- iGIS
- GISRoam
- field_assets
- Geopaparazzi

Possibly you can point me to something with similar functionality to the ArcGIS for iOS?

OR

Interesting programming frameworks to achieve the desired functionality on iOS?

Comment: I use Bit Map ( https://apps.apple.com/au/app/bit-map/id1560781471 ).  But I'm the developer, so I'm biased.  See also:  https://nixanz.com/bitmap/

Answer (score 0):

[Input App](https://inputapp.io/en/) based on QGIS can be used directly on iOS to acquire georeferenced information. Or it can be fully customized since it is open source.

disclaimer: I am one of the developers of the app.

Answer (score -1):

I like GISKit from Garafa, though it too seems to have been forgotten about for a while.  the developers have updated it over time, but it seems its feature set has not expanded, and longstanding bugs still stand.

That said they did a good job with the interface and I find it very intuitive.  I wish it were not an extra $200 just to get access to SHP files and be able to share projects between tablets though.

However, they do support building picklists and customized symbology, the map renders very fast with smooth navigation, offline caching is available too, and recently they added some feature server connectivity.

Still, any time I've emailed them in the last 2 years asking about longstanding bugs or if the app's features are going anywhere new, I don't get a lot of positive feedback from the developer's replies.  They had a huge head start on other GIS apps on tablets, but seem to have lost the lead.  Still, worth checking out.